# electron-builder always show blank page html but after i reload the app with "win + r" button the actuall page show

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, electron

when i build my app using electron-builder, the built success. but there is a problem. After i install the **.exe** file, the app running, but only shows blank page, i checked the devtools, it's just the blank html code. The strange thing considered after i reload the page using **win+r** button, and the actuall page i've expected (login.pug) show.

anyway, here's my ***package.json*** :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^26.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.3"
  },
  "name": "kasir",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "desk.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "dist":"electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId":"cashier-desktop-app",
    "extraResources":["database"],
    "win": {
      "target":"NSIS",
      "icon":"public/foto/FEY-orange.png"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Fath Elchaydir Yahya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Aplikasi Kasir untuk UMKM"
}
```

and here's my ***desk.js*** it's the electron file to render ***main.js*** :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const { dialog } = require('electron');
const path = require('path')

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname+'/main.js'),
      webSecurity: false,
      nodeIntegration: true
    },
    show:false //-----harus di show:false dulu, gak tau kenapa
  });

  mainWindow.maximize();//-----supaya desktop window nya bisa fullscreen
  mainWindow.show();//-----supaya desktop window nya bisa fullscreen

  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
  mainWindow.on('close', function (e) {
    let response = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(this, {
      type: 'question',
      buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
      title: 'PERINGATAN ! :',
      message: `Anda bisa menutup aplikasi ini kapanpun. Namun, jika anda menutupnya karena selesai melakukan jual-beli, disarankan untuk menekan tombol \"CLOSING\" pada halaman \'Kasir\', hal ini perlu dilakukan (opsional) jika anda sangat perhatian terhadap pembaharuan statistik keuangan dan transaksi yang dicatat otomatis setiap hari setelah anda melakukan \"CLOSING\". Lanjut keluar aplikasi ?`
    });

    if(response == 1) e.preventDefault();
  });
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools() //cek error setelah build
}

app.removeAllListeners('ready')

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("resize", function (e, x, y) {
  mainWindow.setSize(x, y);
});

app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `mainWindow.show()` line to after the `mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000")` line?

Comment: no, i haven't. but i'm not sure it could work because i copied desk.js code from the electron documentation, but i think you're idea might be solve my problem, i fully apreciate it :), thx. i'll give it a try.